# How can I capture the AudioDestinationNode value when headphones are plugged in with Web Audio API?

Tags: javascript, html, audio, web-audio-api, headphones

I've been looking for a solution that detects the difference between the default speakers and headphones on a computer. I understand that with Web Audio API, AudioDestinationNode represents the output device, where users hear audio.

My question (to be specific) is whether or not it is possible to detect a change in the users' audio output device (wired/wireless headphones). If this is not possible, is there a way to use phonegap to do so, for computers as well as mobile devices?

My goal is to initiate an event only when the AudioDestinationNode maps to headphones or external speakers.

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing in the Web Audio API spec for this.

It might be possible in Phonegap (at least if you were willing to write your own Phonegap plugin) – but that's only going to help on mobile. As far as I know, there's no way to determine the audio output device in any of the major desktop browsers.

Just out of curiosity, what are you hoping to do as a result of the user switching between built-in speakers and an external device?

Comment: At the moment I'm doing a little homework on techniques for delivering "complete" experiences by only delivering features when there is an indication of intent or willingness to engage. 

At the moment I am working with the music of an artist and some video storytelling. Full-screen + headphones seems to be a good place to start before I can expect comparable experiences between visiting a webpage and using an app. This will also make it easier to keep track of the types of visitors that reach the application.