# Detecting Headphone Jack Insertion and Changing Volume Settings

Tags: c

I would like the volume to change to a set value when I plug in my headphones, preferably using C. I am on Windows 10. I am not sure where to start, I have done some research but haven't gotten anywhere. If you guys could lead me in the right direction that would be great.

Comment: [Programming means that sometimes you have to snap two blocks together](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20090804-00/?p=17233). Find a "block" that tells you when headphones are inserted, find a "block" that lets you change the volume, and snap them together.

Answer (score -2):

What you've found online is right, you can't detect it.

The audio jacks are simple connectors that either send analog signals out or receive them in. They function the same if something is connected to them as when something isn't. They don't have a method for detecting if the hardware is attached or not.

A microphone isn't too bad to detect through software, just listen on the port and if there is no signal at all (no noise) then you can assume that there is nothing connected. The speaker jack is different since you can send sound out all you want and it just won't be heard if there are no speakers attached.

**There's just no way to detect if speakers are there or not**

It would be different if there were a method for measuring continuity through the speaker jack, but there isn't.

To give you some more read... Take a look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33872895/detect-if-headphones-are-plugged-in-or-not-via-c-sharp

I hope it helps.

Comment: Most current system **can** detect plugged-in devices. Whether they do this by measuring the impedance or by a contact operated by the plug doesn' matter. Even my eight year old notebook does this. It stores two different audio levels, one for the built-in speakers and one for the headphones. Both are automatically used. Having said this I should add that the OS is an Arch Linux derivative and not Windows 10, but hey, the hardware detecting exists.