# Detect if default soundcard has changed via VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, core-audio, naudio

I have been trying to detect changes of the default audio playback device in my VB.NET application.

Unfortunately, most examples I could find were based on C#. 
So I tried to translate it to VB.NET, but I seem to do something wrong.

The most simple example I could find was this one:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/33945287/9399239

Despite its simplicity I was not able to to make it work in VB.NET, so that I had to give up.

Could someone perhaps have a very simple example like the one linked, to notify changes of the default sourd device, but in a working VB.NET variant?

Thanks for your kind help.

Comment: We might be able to help if you show where you get stuck with a C# conversion to VB.

Comment: Did you install the [NAudio](https://github.com/naudio/NAudio) NuGet package? After that, change the `void` stuff to `Friend Sub` and you're good to go.